# Eliminar todos los caracteres que no correspondan a letras o comas con PHP

Tags: php, regex

Necesito una función para eliminar todos los caracteres que no sean letras (ABC...) o comas (,).

He usado el str_replace (ya que solo hay unos 8 caracteres que deben ser eliminados, pero no acaba de funcionar muy bien y creo que haba alguna forma mucho mejor para hacerlo pero no sé como.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías subir el código de lo que has intentado? Además una explicación un poco más detallada del problema, y del resultado deseado. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Que quiere decir que no acaba de funcionar bien? cual es el codigo que intentaste? que paso cuando lo intentaste?